# How to Have my JLabels Display Strings stored in my ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

EDIT: Extension of question [How to Get these JPanels to be Display in my JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602016/how-to-get-these-jlabels-to-be-displayed-in-my-jframe).

I am attempting to make a "sentence randomizer" that, when a button is pressed, makes a grammatically correct sentence by looping different types of words from a separate folder and separate files. The issue that I am encountering is that I am unable to figure out how to get the retrieved words displayed within the JLabels. Here is my code so far to clarify:

```
package user_interface;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import code.sentence;
import user_interface.RandomButtonListener;

public class sentenceUI {

    private sentence _s;
    private JButton _rando;

    public sentenceUI() {
        _s = new sentence(this);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Ryan Ellis' Lab 9");
        f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        f.add(topPanel);

        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel();
        f.add(lowerPanel);

        _rando = new JButton("Random Sentence");
        _rando.addActionListener(new RandomButtonListener(_s, this));
        lowerPanel.add(_rando);

        ArrayList<JLabel> _labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        Color c1 = Color.BLUE;
        Color c2 = new Color( 255 - c1.getRed(), 255 - c1.getGreen(), 255 - c1.getBlue()); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            JLabel _l = new JLabel();
            _l.setOpaque(true);
            _l.setBackground(c1);
            _l.setForeground(c2);
            Color temp = c1;
                    c1 = c2;
                    c2 = temp;
            _l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,8,5));
            _l.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 18));
        topPanel.add(_l);
        }

        ArrayList<String> _slst = new ArrayList<String>();
            _slst.add("WordLists/adjectives.txt");
            _slst.add("WordLists/adverbs.txt");
            _slst.add("WordLists/determiners.txt");
            _slst.add("WordLists/nouns.txt");
            _slst.add("WordLists/verbs.txt");

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        list.add(_slst);
            int i = 0;
            list.get(i % 5);



        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();

    }

    private void createRButton(String string, JPanel lowerPanel) {
        createRButton("Random", lowerPanel);


    }
}
```

Comment: why not make it 1 string and add it to jtextfield?

Comment: and where do you look through the files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to Get these JLabels to be Displayed in my JFrame?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40602016/230513); please clarify and cite the original question.

Comment: In the _slst ArrayList I add "WordLists/adjectives.txt" with WordLists being the folder and the word type being the file. Also, this is not a duplicate, this is a different question, I'll cite the original.

Comment: @sqwert Perhaps you want to show us your desired output. I am not sure what is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `JLabel`s in some sort of list so you can retrieve their instance later, after you've generated a random sentence.

Then you can do

```
jlabel.setText(string)
```

and after you've added all the words, you may have to repaint the JPanel (with jpanel.repaint()) to update the JLabel's display.

Comment: I added the JLabels to an ArrayList _labels. Where would I place the JLabel.setText(string)? I can't seem to make it work, I've tried placing it after the JLabels, within the for loop, after that, and right after the ArrayList for the words themselves, I'm not sure I really understand what I'm doing with it, haha.

Comment: When you've generated the sentence, like you said your code does. The `setText` method is for setting what text that JLabel represents